# c# set active menu on a tree list from bottom up

Tags: c#, list, tree

I have a class:

```
public class Menu
{
     public Menu()
     {
          this.Children = new List<Menu>();
     }

     public string MenuId { get; set; }
     public string Title { get; set; }
     public bool IsActive { get; set; }
     public List<Menu> Children { get; set; }    
}
```

Now I have a List:

```
List<Menu> menu = new List<Menu>();
```

Given a MenuId let's say 20, how can I recursively set the property IsActive to all parents of the Menu where MenuId = 20?

[image]

Here is my attempt:

```
  List<Menu> menu = new List<Menu>

        foreach (Menu _menu in menu)
        {
            if (_menu.MenuId == _id)
            {
                _menu.IsActive = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                SetActive(_menu, _id);
            }
        }

    private void SetActive(Menu menu, string _id)
    {
        foreach (Menu _menu in menu.Children)
        {
            if (_menu.MenuId == targetContentId)
            {
                _menu.IsActive = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                SetActive(_menu, _id);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Should `IsActive` be a `bool`?

Comment: Recurse down until you find the matching item and then set `IsActive` as you unwind.

Comment: @DaveZych: yes it is bool. My mistake.

Comment: @MattBurland: Actually I did that (I added the sample code). The problem is I don't know how to set IsActive for the parents of that item. So now when I found the item, how can i traverse it from down up in order to set IsActive for all it's parents until the root item?

Comment: Also consider using a visitor pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586586/search-through-hierarchicaldata-with-recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (assuming ids are unique within the whole structure):

```
bool FindAndSet(int id, List<Menu> menu)
{
    foreach (var m in menu)
    {
        if (m.MenuId == id)    // base case, this is the item we are looking for
        {
            m.IsActive = true;
            return true;
        }
        else if (m.Children == null || m.Children.Count == 0)
        {
            return false;    // other base case, no more children
        }
        var found = FindAndSet(id, m.Children);    // recurse
        if (found)                                 // if we found it in our descendants
        {
            m.IsActive = true;                     // set is active as we unwind
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Just one small comment: I replaced the `return false;    // other base case, no more children` with `continue;` otherwise at the first branch of the tree if there are no more children it will stop.

Answer (score 1):

Let `Menu` have an **event** (for example, it could implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but it could also have a more strongly typed `IsActiveChanged` event).

Raise that event whenever `IsActive` changes.

Let all parents subscribe to their immediate childrens' events, and update their own `IsActive` value accordingly.

Comment: Sounds great I never used the INotifyPropertyChanged before. I could give it a try. Why not?